# Wrap and move data using only functions and variables (experimental programming)

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, toplevel

I was programming with kotlin for fun and i tried to make an experiment:

Wrap and move data only using functions (classes and data classes are not allowed)

My first attempt resulted on the code below:

```kotlin
// I've created a function structure that allows me to keep data of a "Person" in memory:
package org.example

typealias InvocableParameter = (String) -> (() -> Any?)?

fun personConstructor(
    name: String,
    age: Int,
    mother: InvocableParameter = { null }): InvocableParameter {
    return { parameter: String ->
        when (parameter) {
            "name" -> {
                { name }
            }
            "age" -> {
                { age }
            }
            "mother" -> {
                { mother }
            }
            "toJson" -> {
                { "{ \"name\": \"$name\", \"age\": $age }" }
            }
            else -> null
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val johnObject = personConstructor(
        "john", 20,
        personConstructor(
            "Lory", 40,
            personConstructor("Eva", 60)
        )
    )
    println(johnObject("toJson")?.invoke())
    val johnsMother = johnObject("mother")?.invoke() as InvocableParameter
    val johnsGrandma = (johnsMother.invoke("mother")?.invoke()) as InvocableParameter
    println(johnsMother.invoke("toJson")?.invoke())
    println(johnsGrandma.invoke("toJson")?.invoke())
}

// Outputs:
// { "name": "john", "age": 20 }
// { "name": "Lory", "age": 40 }
// { "name": "Eva", "age": 60 }
```

What are another approaches that I could have used to achieve my initial goal on a more elegant manner?

I've tried to crate a structure that allowed me to store and move data only using functions. I'm expecting to achieve that goal in a smart and elegant way.

Comment: It might help if you could explain a bit more about _why_ you want to encapsulate everything in functions. (It looks to me as if you're trying to reinvent objects — ingenious and interesting, but fragile, long-winded, not type-safe, non-discoverable, hard to read, and inefficient. And I doubt many of those can be improved.) Is this just to see if it can be done at all? (If so, I think you've achieved that!) But if you want to actually use it, well, what would be the benefit over the much more practical and better-supported objects Kotlin already has?

Comment: I was testing the language to see if would be possible to build a complete system using functions. Yeah, you are right, the build in features of the language are better suited for the propose of my question. But I was just trying to make experiments just for fun and "art" haha.